# ISupportIncrementalLoading Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, pagination, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8.1 application which will make use of the `ISupportIncrementalLoading` on a `GridView`.
However I've tried multiple tutorials:

- [Tutorial 1](http://eren.ws/2013/10/30/infinite-scrolling-in-windows-store-apps-using-isupportincrementalloading-boredom-challenge-day-26/)
- [Tutorial 2](http://www.davidbritch.com/2014/05/data-virtualisation-using.html)
- [Tutorial 3](http://michelsalib.com/2012/10/21/winrt-how-to-properly-implement-isupportincrementalloading-with-navigation/)

I can't seem to figure out my how to make it work properly.

The api works with pagination:
I have a model which wraps around my object I use as an `ItemsSource`.

```
public class ResponseGetProducts : ObservableObject
{        
    public ResponseGetProduct[] products { get; set; } //the bindable property  
    public uint pages { get; set; } //amount of pages in total
}
```

Don't know if it's relevant but the `ResponseGetProduct`-class

```
public class ResponseGetProduct : ObservableObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long remote_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public string remote_page { get; set; }
    public uint status { get; set; }
    public long[] related_ids { get; set; }
    public ResponseImage[] images { get; set; }
}
```

In my ViewModel I have a property

```
private IncrementalResponseList _ginsIncrementalResponseList;
public IncrementalResponseList GinsIncrementalResponseList
{
    get
    {
       return new IncrementalResponseList();
    }
    set
    {
        Set(() => GinsIncrementalResponseList, ref _ginsIncrementalResponseList, value);
    }
}
```

In my XAML I have

```
<GridView
    ItemsSource="{Binding GinsIncrementalResponseList}"
    ... />
```

How can I use the `ISupportIncrementalLoading`-interface to make the list add items from the pages when scrolled?

I made this in pseudo code:

```
public class IncrementalResponseList : ObservableCollection<ResponseGetProduct>, ISupportIncrementalLoading
{

    public IncrementalResponseList()
    {

    }

    public bool HasMoreItems
    {
        get
        {
            //true if the count of the pages has not been reached;
            pageID++; //up the current page
        }
    }

    public IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
    {
        CoreDispatcher dispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;

        return Task.Run<LoadMoreItemsResult>(() =>
        {
            dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
            {
                var result = await _service.GetAllGins(pageID); //method to fetch the products
                foreach (var product in result.products)
                {
                    Add(product);
                }
            });


            return new LoadMoreItemsResult() { Count = //the api returns a maximum of 3 items per page. };
        }).AsAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult>();
    }
}
```